# how to deregister chosen javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

Hi I have searched for answer to this question by following examples likes:
[How to properly dequeue scripts and styles in child theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189985/how-to-properly-dequeue-scripts-and-styles-in-child-theme),but nothing is working.  I created a child theme for my template.  My page is not working properly with the chosen.css and chosen.jquery.min.js.  In the parent function.php when I comment out the lines it works:

```js
    //wp_register_style('chosen', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/libraries/chosen/chosen.css');
        wp_register_style('colorbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/libraries/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css');
        wp_register_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');

        wp_enqueue_style('font');
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-responsive');
        //wp_enqueue_style('chosen');    
// wp_register_script('chosen', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/libraries/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '', TRUE);
        wp_register_script('iosslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/libraries/iosslider/_src/jquery.iosslider.min.js', array('jquery'), '', TRUE);
        //wp_register_script('chosen', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/libraries/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '', TRUE);
```

In the child theme i have this code:

```js
//Dequeue Styles
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'chosen' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'chosen' );
}

//Dequeue JavaScripts
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'chosen' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'chosen' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'chosen.jquery.min.js' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'chosen.jquery.min.js' );
}
```

The child theme code is not working and everything I find points me to this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you may be missing the `add_action` from after the functions you declared...? similar question on WP forums: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/child-theme-removing-scripts-from-parent-functionsphp

Comment: well those are trying to use a different style sheet.  I am using the same one just not these lines of code so I did not included it.

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean you do actually have eg. `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts', 100 );` for example in your code, you just didn't include that line...?

Comment: @webeno is right - as it stands, although the function is there, nothing calls it without the `add_action(...`

Comment: @webeno you are right i was missing that and it works now.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `add action` function call. Add it and it will work.

Example code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts', 100 );
```